# Selenium Server starts Firefox, but Firefox doesn't load RemoteRunner

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium, ubuntu-11.04

Moving my main build/test server over to a new place and updating the operating system as I do so. It's working (if running out of memory and timing out often) on the old server. The new server has more memory and processor and also is running a newer operating system.

The server is Ubuntu 11.04, Natty, running Vnc4 server from a remote datacenter.

Selenium IDE 1.6.0 is installed in Firefox (though had to force a profile to get it to actually remember that it's installed).

Firefox is installed at version 10.0.1

Selenium Server 2.9.0 is running in gnome terminal launched from a VNC window.

It runs and opens port 4444 properly.

I start my python test suite (which, remember, works fine on the old server) and it calls 
    self.selenium.start()

At that point the connection to Selenium Server opens, Selenium server says it's found a "get new browser" request on session null, then it allocates a session with a long hexcode, says is preparing Firefox, then launching Firefox.

Then the firefox window opens.

All good so far.

In the old, working, setup Firefox then opens a chrome://src/content/RemoteRunner.html URL to bring up the selenium remote control page.

In the new server Firefox just sits there waiting, doing nothing, on a blank page.

Don't really know enough about how Selenium works to know what's going on here. Is the Selenium Server supposed to have launched Firefox with a URL, which it's somehow failed to do? Or is it supposed to just launch a blank one and then talk to hooks in the Selenium IDE which it's failing to do?

Anyone have any clue how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, and it seems it does eventually come back with an exception after 1800 seconds:

Exception: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1805.999s

Comment: Right, looking at the selenium source-code, it seems that Selenium Server builds a profile and sets the profile's homepage to the remoteRunner.html page then launches Firefox with that profile. So I checked the homepage setting of the firefox which is launched, and that does indeed seem to be set for the RemoteRunner.html page. Yet clicking "home" doesn't take me there. And copy/pasting that URL into the address-bar in the Firefox also just shows a blank page..... Confusing.

Comment: Ahha, there's an error in the javascript console. Why didn't I think to look there before? --> No chrome package registered for chrome://src/content/RemoteRunner.html...  <- Presumably that means the IDE hasn't installed properly or something?

Comment: Reinstalled it, and at first launch there's the javascript error "Could not read chrome manifest file '/usr/lib/firefox-10.0.1/extensions/{972ce4c5-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/chrome.manifest" which isn't surprising since that file isn't there. The directory is, there's icon.png and install.rdf and preview.png but no chrome.manifest. This is surely the problem. So the question now is, why isn't it there and how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an "Answer", but having spent two days on this now I just don't have time to look at it any more so I've given up and just installed Chromium to use that for running the tests rather than Firefox. I mean *really* I ought to use both but I guess this will have to do for now.

Answer (score -1):

I have also got the same problem and the following procedure has solved the issue.

check firefox version on ubuntu using the following command.
firefox --version
Only firefox prior to version 42 only supports selenium.
If the version of firefox on ubuntu is greater than 42, then follow the commands below to install firefox42.

Open Terminal and run the following commands to install Firefox on 32 bit Linux Ubuntu Systems:

```
$ wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/42.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
$ tar -xjvf firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/firefox*
$ sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox
$ sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Open Terminal and run the following commands to install Firefox on 64 bit Linux Ubuntu Systems:

```
$ wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/42.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
$ tar -xjvf firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/firefox*
$ sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox
$ sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

---- Murali Mohan T